# zsh shell is not showing git branch name

Tags: zshrc

I have following code in my `.zshrc` file.
When I go to my repos and the **git branch name** is not showing up on the **right side of the console** until I source the .zshrc file with

source ~/.zshrc

```
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

RPS1=`parse_git_branch`
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you use Oh-My-Zsh

https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh

It has great options and git support out of the box (branch names, coloring, stash...)

Comment: I agree, the link is great, but could you please provide more details from the link...

Comment: zshrc is a cool tool but with 250+ plugins business security sometimes blocks its usage. Any idea how to do without the tools?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `vcs_info`:

```
autoload -Uz vcs_info
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' enable git
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' formats '(%b)'
precmd() { vcs_info }
setopt prompt_subst
RPROMPT='${vcs_info_msg_0_}'
```

This is already included with zsh.